# Thickbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use Thickbox in my site.
I have the following code:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("GetSchemaImage", "Hall", new {folderName = @Model.FolderName })' class="thickbox"><img src='@Url.Action("GetSchemaImage", "Hall", new {folderName = @Model.FolderName })'/></a>
```

This is generated markup:

```
<a class="thickbox" href="/Hall/GetSchemaImage?folderName=marineclub"><img src="/Hall/GetSchemaImage?folderName=marineclub"></a>
```

The image shows correctly, but when I click on it, it opens in the current window.

How to resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: What is javascript code for attaching Thickbox behavior? Are you sure it is included on page? If yes, do you get any errors in console?

Comment: There is no error. I think it can understand url.

Answer (score 0):

try another signature for the HTML ActionLink helper and see if this works

```
@Html.ActionLink("GetSchemaImage", "Hall",new {folderName = @Model.FolderName },new{})
```

Comment: sorry, typo. i said it right: Html extension methods. its @Html not Url.